# Disambiguate the [learning] tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

The [learning](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) tag seems to fall in two (or three) categories:

- One about **new riders,** which should be retagged as the winner of the [new-rider](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-rider)/[beginner](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) merge
- One about **skills,** which should be retagged as [technique](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique)
- One about **tricks,** which should either go to [tricks](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tricks) or to [technique](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that **as a first step we should go through all the "learning" questions and simply retag them with the appropriate "about what?" topic**, and then sort the tags out from there; we don't need to hash out skills vs. technique at this point, that's just going to confuse things and slow them down.

I agree that [learning](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) needs to go; after all isn't "learning" most of what we are here to help with?  Most answerable questions solicit information; almost anything could be considered "learning."  Learning about how to match tyre size to wheels.  Learning about how to fix stripped bolts.  Learning about how to choose appropriate cycling gear.  Und so weiter.  (Pretty much the only on-topic questions that wouldn't fit as "learning" are the identify-my-bike questions.)

Further, "learning" appears to me to be what SE would consider a meta-tag, and [meta-tags are discouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  (It hardly makes sense for a contributor to be an expert in "learning.")  For any post tagged with "learning," it should be possible to answer "about what?" and *that* should be the topic the question is tagged with.  (It is possible that we need some new tags, or some tag reorganisation, to complete this.)

One thing to note is that there are a number of questions tagged "learning" that are actually about *teaching* skills (e.g. to children).  I'd rather not have the goal of getting rid of [learning](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) resulting in another meta-tag like [teaching](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) (again, *about what?*), but it's probably most appropriate to tag those with [new-rider](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-rider) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Learning can also apply to bicycle mechanics (learning the trade, or at least to be more self-sufficient in bicycle repair/maintenance).

Learning could also apply to racing (strategy, training), and bike fitting (becoming proficient at bike fitting as a trade or simply becoming self-aware of how ones' bike fit can be optimized for themselves).

I do not believe that skills is always synonymous with technique.  For example, bicycle mechanics is a learned skill but technique can not be used in place of skills here. In riding, however, a case for riding-skills can often be translated to riding-technique.